# Using pandas to consider all possible time interval of 1 hour when counting events

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

For example we have this sample data frame

```
event_time          | orderid        |  shopid   | userid   
2019-12-28 20:20:18 | 31075224830298 |  9466594  | 84811421 
2019-12-28 21:00:00 | 31075407131046 |  9466594  | 84811421 
2019-12-28 21:01:51 | 31124082143295 |  9466594  | 84811421 
2019-12-28 21:03:55 | 31124471136339 |  9466594  | 84811421 
2019-12-28 21:42:59 | 31126319757758 |  9466594  | 2141942
```

I want to count number of orders for a particular shop within an hour and also the number of unique users within the same hour. I have tried using rolling function from pandas,

```
df.rolling('H').count()['orderid']
```

but it's purely looking at the event_time that I have in the data i.e. for order 31126319757758, it looks at 1 hour interval from 20:42 to 21:42 where I can see 4 orders from 2 users. But this method can't tell me the 1 hour interval say from 20:20 to 21:20 or from 20:30 to 21:30 which both tells me only 1 user bought from the shop within that 1 hour time interval.

Is there a way to achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Code below uses `.rolling(window='1h')` in [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/computation.html) to get rolling count during an hour. Key is to set `event_time` as `index`. Note that when using timeseries rolling, the `min_periods=1` as default. This number could be changed if needed to introduce NaN's in place of the counts for before `1h` timepoint.

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'event_time':[pd.Timestamp(x) for x in ['2019-12-28 20:20:18','2019-12-28 21:00:00','2019-12-28 21:01:51','2019-12-28 21:03:55','2019-12-28 21:42:59']],
    'orderid':[31075224830298,31075407131046,31124082143295,31124471136339,31126319757758],
    'shopid':[9466594,9466594,9466594,9466594,9466594],
    'userid':[84811421,84811421,84811421,84811421,2141942]
})

# Set 'event_time' as index
df = df.set_index('event_time')

# Use .rolling() with window='1h'
df['order_count'] = df['orderid'].rolling(window='1h').count()
df['unique_cust_count'] = df['userid'].rolling(window='1h').apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
df

# Output
```

[image]